# selectively using different range sliders using Algolia instantsearch.js

Tags: javascript, algolia

With Algolia Instantsearch.js I'm looking to selectively use different rangeSliders depending on the value of a passed country_code parameter in the query string.

If e.g: the country_code is 'FR' I want to use a total_area_meters range slider, and use another range slider that uses euros. For the 'UK' I want to use total_area_ft and another range slider that uses pounds.

Though I'm waiting (and hoping) for https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/753 to be implemented, I've been told by Algolia support personnel that it's potentially possible to use the helper library: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js to get this working.

I have e.g: experimented with selectively enabling disjunctive facets using:

```
search.addWidget({
  init: function (opts) {
    // opts.helper contains the underlying algoliasearchHelper
    if(detected_locale === 'fr'){
        opts.helper.setQueryParameter('disjunctiveFacets', [
            'total_area_meters','price_eur'
            ]); 
//...
```

Though doing this is not enough: among other issues, there are still slider widgets on the page e.g: requiring 'total_area_feet, and 'price_gbp' which raise javascript errors - I need to disable them somehow, and also there are quite obtrusive urls that need to be selectively removed.

e.g: If my disjunctive facet is: total_area_meters: I get a url like this:

`&nR[total_area_meters][>=][0]=135&nR[total_area_meters][<=][0]=770` - which needs to be removed when I have a country_code where feet are used, instead.

So my questions about this are:

- Is there a way to selectively enable/disable instantsearch.js rangeslider widgets programmatically via js? (or can I somehow programmatically set their values/ reset them so they have no query parameters?)
- If not covered in the solution above, are there any pre-built functions for me to clean up the rangeslider url parameters? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from Tim Carry at Algolia, I was able to get a work-around working. It's not perfect, but in a nutshell, I first added all my sliders to the page. I then selectively hid them using:

```
.hideClass { 
    display: none; 
}
$sliders[i].addClass('hideClass');
// or
$sliders[i].removeClass('hideClass');
```

This performs much better than:

```
$sliders[i].show()
//and
$sliders[i].hide()
```

Depending on the country_code in the url.
I found that it's (unfortunately) necessary to re-issue hiding/showing commands on each render call (not just on `init()`) e.g:

```
search.addWidget( {
  render: function(opts) {
    show_hide_sliders();
  }
});
```

It's possible to remove all url parameters for a slider using:

```
helper.removeNumericRefinement(slider_attribute[i]);
```

which is only issued if there is a country_code change.
And it pretty-much seems to function (though caveat: only limited testing so far). Hope this is helpful to someone.

EDIT:
To respond to the comments, a note: in this case I got a handle on the helper by using opts.helper (but I probably might have also succeeded using search.helper, too.). e.g:

```
search.addWidget( {
  render: function(opts) {
    show_hide_sliders();
    opts.helper. ... // add your helper methods...
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Can you also say how did you access the underlying helper? To anyone reading this, we are also working on being able to update the configuration of widgets dynamically: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/753

Comment: Hi @vvo I Edited my answer. Glad to hear you're working on the dynamic configuration!